# Python print output while embedding Python in C\C++

Tags: python, stdout, python-embedding

Where does Python `print` to, if the `print` statement is in a python function, called from C\C++ in an embedded Python configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, the `print` statement writes into `sys.stdout` (which is the standard output) even in an embedded app, you should see your prints in the console that started the application.